# Prove that all cycles are identities

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory

In the following commutative diagram:

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
A & \longleftrightarrow & B \\
\updownarrow & & \updownarrow \\
C & \longleftrightarrow & D
\end{array}
$$

all arrows are isomorphisms (and the inverse isomorphisms in the reverse direction).

Prove that for the every cycle in this diagram to be an identity, it is enough that there exists an identity cycle of the length $4$.

I am writing a book and want a clear proof appropriate for very beginners in category theory.

Note that there are more commutative diagrams in my book, so I may need a lemma helping with other proofs (for different diagrams) like this.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of proof you're looking for. Personally, I'd show this result for any given group and any finite circle using conjugation.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f : A \to B$, $g : C \to D$, $u : A \to C$, $v : B \to D$ be isomorphisms with
$u^{-1} g^{-1} vf = \mathrm{id}$, i.e. the clockwise cycle starting at $A$ gives the identity. Taking inverses on both sides, we get the corresponding anti-clockwise circle. Multiplying with $f$ on the left and with $f^{-1}$ on the right, we get $f u^{-1} g^{-1} v = \mathrm{id}$, which is the clockwise cycle starting at $B$. The rest follows by rotation.

Comment: I want a more detailed proof

Comment: Ok, then write it down.